# Issues removing text decoration from links in a custom block

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I'm replacing the Bartik menu with a custom one. To do this, I'm building a custom block and placing it appropriately.

That all works. However, I am having issues with Text Decoration: No matter what I try, I cannot remove the line from under links, and I have also noticed a "Doubled/offset" text look. When I edit the code on 'Tryit', everything looks fine; when I unclick 'source' in the block editor, everything also looks fine.

When I update the page, I see these issues.

My entire block code is the following one.

```
<style type="text/css">body {margin:0;}
    ul.topnav {
      font-weight: normal;
      text_decoration: none;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }

    ul.topnav li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    ul.topnav li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }       

   ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

   ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

   @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
     ul.topnav li {display: none;}
     ul.topnav li.icon {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
      ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
      }
      ul.topnav.responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
    </style>
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#extra">Extra</a></li>
        <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()" style="font-size:15px;">☰ Menu ☰</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Here is an image of the issue:

[image: Menu Issue]

Notice both the underline, and the 'Doubled text'? Thats what Im trying to get rid of. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have a typo "text_decoration: none;"

Comment: Thank you for catching that, I fixed the code but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the text-decoration, try to use !important attribute.

For that "doubled text", you need to use text-shadow: none.

If text-decoration still doesn't work, you can try border-bottom: none for that line, too.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out yesterday with help from the Drupal Community, The issue was the page CSS overriding my code.

To fix it I did exactly what you sugest, I used text-shadow: none; & border-bottom: none;

Thank you.